# jsonPath: how confirm the data returned is just one element? and when it is not an array

Tags: jsonpath, spring-test-mvc

I am working with:

- Spring MVC
- Spring MVC Testing

Assuming that a `@Controller` working with `@ResponseBody` returns a set of domain objects represented in JSON format and through `print()` method I can confirm the following:

```
Body = [ {
  "id" : "88",
  "nombre" : "Manuel",
  "apellido" : "Jordan",
  "fecha" : 1449370807750
}, {
  "id" : "87",
  "nombre" : "Leonardo",
  "apellido" : "Jordan",
  "fecha" : 1449370807750
}, {
  ...
}, {
  ...
}, {
  ...
} ]
```

Observe that content is an array.

Through Spring MVC Testing and with *hamcrest* I have the following:

```
resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath('$').exists())
        .andExpect(jsonPath('$').isArray())
        .andExpect(jsonPath('$',hasSize(5)))
…
```

Until here all work fine.

But assuming the `@Controller` returns just one element (One Domain Object) and again through the `print()` method I can see the following:

```
Body = {
  "id" : "100",
  "nombre" : "Jesús Você",
  "apellido" : "Mão Nuñez",
  "fecha" : 1449372342312
}
```

Observe it is *not* an array

I have currently the following:

```
resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath('$').exists())
           //.andExpect(jsonPath('$').isArray()) <--- fails                   
             .andExpect(jsonPath('$.*', hasSize(4) ))
```

How I can confirm the data returned is just one element? 
It when is not an array.

I mean, I want have the same approach/behaviour about the following from XML

```
<persona>
    <id>100</id>
    <nombre>Jesús Você</nombre>
    <apellido>"Mão Nuñez"</apellido>
    <fecha>2015-12-05T22:00:07.756-05:00</fecha>
</persona>
```

Through

```
resultActions.andExpect(xpath("persona").exists())
             .andExpect(xpath("persona").nodeCount(1))
```

Practically, what is the *equivalent* of `xpath("persona").nodeCount(1)` to *jsonPath*?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what library or version of jsonpath you are using, but in the current version (0.13.0) at https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath/ , you will want the option `wrap: true` (the default).

Comment: Hello I am working with Gradle and I have the following: 
`compile 'org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0'` and `compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.0.0'`

Comment: sorry, I'm working with JavaScript, not Java. (Should have gotten that from "Spring")